# GDAL/BUILD can't get result files Geojson to mbtiles

Tags: gdal, ogr, json, mbtiles

i try to 2.55gb of GeoJson (maybe 200 over layers in one file) to vector Mbtiles, but fail to create .mbtiles.

so i try convert each layers(.shp) to geojson(over 200 files), 
then create each .mbtiles. but works it.

so i try to edit gdal source for console debug message,
end the compile, try to geosjon to mbtiles(Previously successful file),
but now... cannot error, but cannot create mbtiles file!

summary.

1. 2.55gb of Geojson to mbtiles fail(using gdal 2.3.0ver Binaries)

   - what is problem? many layer? or json's size?
2. custom gdal(just add console print) can't create mbtiles file.

   - What should I identify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try using [tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe)?

Simpler guide, do refer to: https://openmaptiles.org/docs/generate/custom-vector-from-shapefile-geojson/

Comment: I installed it, but I have not tried it yet.
This is because the tippecanoe does not know whether the zoom level can be different for each layer.
i'll try it with default options. Thank you.

Comment: thank you for your help, i can create mbtiles, now i'll try each layer zoom setting,
There are a few problems, but let me think.